# Fancybox with MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, fancybox

I have an issue with fancybox not loading in razor view engine. I have
all the js/css loaded in correctly (I've tested to make sure fancybox
works with a simple video link, it did). So the error is likely somewhere in
the code below.

On the page:
The parent view contains a list of links, each needs to open in its
own fancybox and load the corresponding view.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
            $("a.className").fancybox({
            (style stuff)
            'type': 'ajax'
           });

         } catch (ex) {
             console.log(ex);
         }
});
```

And the link itself:

```
<div class="className">
    <span class="spanName">
        @Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Action", new { id = Model.ID })
    </span>
</div>
```

Any ideas? I'll provide more code if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link doesn't have a class assigned to it so the selector `'a.className'` won't match anything. Try changing the link to `@Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Action", new { id = Model.ID }, new { @class = "className" })`

Comment: This is close but not right. Actually it's: @Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Action", new { id = Model.ID}, new { @class = "className" })